# PhoneGap + Event Kit Framework?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, sencha-touch, eventkit

I've looked through PhoneGap forums and documentation, and I'm not seeing any information on this. I'm just getting started with mobile development using Sencha Touch and PhoneGap, and wondering how possible / difficult it is to access the iPhone calendar through Event Kit Framework using these JavaScript-based tools.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not part of PhoneGap's core API, however plenty of people have created their own plugins. As such, there is not yet a universal cross-platform solution.

You'll be able to find the plugins that people have already written on [the PhoneGap mail lists](http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/search?q=calendar&start=0&scoring=d&pli=1). Proceed with caution, however, as these are not tested and the majority are loaded with bugs.

Good luck! Hope you find an implementation that works for you.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. This is helpful. For now, I might find another solution, but this made me hopeful for the future: "Good to see you are looking at tackling the Calendar API.  That is something we have on our roadmap post 1.0 release of PhoneGap." http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/1dfe5c147c91d0be/6da5ead7cf12bead

Answer (score 1):

i just posted a calendar plugin for ios in the github project for phonegap
link: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/CalendarPlugin